# how do i make list of tables and list of figures?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

my table like this

```
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
     a & b & c
     \end{tabular}
```

without any caption so do i make list of tables. it just sample of this.

Comment: What would you like to appear in the list of tables here then? Just a page number?

Comment: no want to add table name and page no. . table name , i write normally like this Table 1 - tablename  no caption

Comment: With other words: An empty caption?

Comment: no caption in  simple line add below of table with no

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\endtabular}{\captionof{table}[\tablename: \thetable]{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\section{First table}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
\end{tabular} 


\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
\end{tabular} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Another version**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{caption}


\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\section{First table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Some caption}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Some another caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's work to do for the `empty` caption justification, of course

Comment: @touhami: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you refer to the `{}` after `\thetable`?

Comment: no no, may the OP mean that caption is "no caption" (may be).

Comment: @touhami: Ah, ok ... well, that might be the case, yes, but honestly, I did not understand the question (really, so far)

Comment: let us wait for his comment

Comment: how to add source in this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I guess that OP actually like to have caption (below table?) but only with caption text (without "Table <num>" before it). If my guessing is right, than he need new macro for those texts, which can be captured by LoT

Comment: @Zarko: This might be but the question is not easy to understand